# SQLPlus connection timeout options

Tags: oracle, timeout, connection, sqlplus

We saw an issue other day, where the database server was responding to tnsping and not responding when trying to establish a connection..

When we tried to connect to the DB.. It was just stuck there and never to login prompt.

So, what I'm trying to do here is to monitor the DB every 5 mins. In case of the above scinero. I may hang again in the same place..

Is there any connection timeout parameter while calling sqlplus.

I'm using the below call

sqlplus -s $constring @justexit.sql

Is there any connection timeout option, which will comeout after waiting for sometime.

Regards,
Senny

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how running this sqlplus script will work (disclaimer: unless it's part of a batch etc). Even if you're inserting the data into a table if you can't select from it again, due to timeout issues, then it's not going to help you. We have a similar system in place to monitor server load, which then goes into a table but to monitor whether the database is timing out, it makes more sense to use something like python to attempt to do something every 5 minutes and e-mail if it times out.

The timeout interval is described here: 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch3.htm

Comment: This is part of the shell script and it is just executing the exit command present in justexit.sql file.. All we want to see is ,if the DB is accepting connection.